# iTunes link in Facebook post does not pull in App description

Tags: ios, facebook, itunes

I'm trying to post a link to the iTunes page for my app on Facebook. It's showing the app icon and app title correctly, but below the app title there should be a description and it's completely blank.

Surely this is something iTunes should automatically be populating and therefore Facebook should be displaying it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not directly related to programming.

Comment: How do you know that these are not variables set in the app's metadata?

Comment: It can actually be related to programmation because I have the same problem when I post the itunes link of my app using the facebook api from my app. You can do whatever you want, nothing will be displayed on the description...